# Wicked pdf - javascript debugging

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I am creating a pdf using the Wicked pdf gem and adding page numbers using the [example in the gem documentation](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#page-numbering).

Is there anyway to use `console.log` or `debugger` so I can step through the implementation to gain a better understanding of what the code is doing?

Answer (score 1):

Since the wkhtmltopdf binary is run outside of your Rails application, I was unable to use `debugger` or `console.log` or `pry` the best strategy I could find for debugging was to create elements and populate their text with the `var` in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome's dev tools to step-in, step-out, and step-over functions after your debugger statement.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Answer (score 0):

Have you used Pry, Pry Debugger, or Pry Debug? That's how we generally dig deeper in rails projects (which one you choose depends on the level of control over navigating such as next, step, finish, etc.)

- https://github.com/pry/pry
- https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry_debug
- https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger